# Helm and custom commands

Tags: helm, interactive

If I write a command that calls `(interactive "f")`, Emacs will prompt the user to select a file when the command is run interactively. With Helm enabled, this selection is done through Helm with no additional effort -- this is great!

However, if I mark multiple files in the Helm selection window, it is not clear to me that this information is passed on to the command. Is there a way to get custom commands to cooperate with Helm and multiple selections?

Comment: Are you sure about the 'no additional effort' bit? I just recently installed Helm and `(defun my-test (files) (interactive "f") (message "%S" files))` isn't invoking Helm for me.

Comment: With only `(require 'helm) (require 'helm-config) (require 'helm-files) (helm-mode 1)` my commands work with Helm (tried from `emacs -Q`).

Comment: Interesting; I see what you mean. The above `defun` messages only the file under point when Helm exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple selections, you have to explicitly retrieve:

```
(helm-marked-candidates :with-wildcard t)
```

and explicitly process the selections. Try printing the return value of the above form to see if you get correct set of candidates.