# Interactive call aware function test problem ( Wrong type argument: commandp )

Tags: interactive, error

Below what the `*Messages*` buffer tells me:

```
Loading init.el (source)...
interactive-aware-fun called-interactively-p : nil
command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, interactive-aware-fun
```

and an excerpt from the `init.el` file:

```
(defun interactive-aware-fun ()
    (message "interactive-aware-fun called-interactively-p : %s" (called-interactively-p))
)
(interactive-aware-fun)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'interactive-aware-fun)
```

Why does a <kbd>F9</kbd> press give me the message:

```
command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, interactive-aware-fun
```

?

Comment: How about adding `(interactive)` before the `(message ...)` inside the function named `interactive-aware-fun`?

Comment: "*3.3 Make a Function Interactive*":  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Interactive.html

Comment: @lawlist or Claudio: Please post that as an answer. Q&A need to stand on their own. Comments aren't searchable, and they can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: The error was produced by `command-execute`, so the first thing to  do is `C-h f command-execute`. E.g. try `(command-execute 'interactive-aware-fun`)`.

Comment: @Claudio -- please feel free to write up an answer at your convenience.

Comment: **Message to future visitors**: the below provided answer is worth to be checked out as it adds more details and consider the specific context of detecting from within a function if it was called interactively or from elisp code than the generic answer about how to avoid the experienced error linked in the hint about being a duplicate.

Comment: @Drew what about deleting your comment about lack of an answer?

Comment: @lawlist what about deleting your comments I have incorporated into the answer?

Comment: It's a useful reminder. It's very often that users of the site, especially new ones, try to use comments beyond what they're for in SE. You included, BTW. ;-) Compare your commenting in your Q&A with others. It's good to understand that any comments can disappear any time. As long as the long stream of comments here remains, my comments here about not relying on comments are useful, IMO. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The way you define a function is important when this function has to be called by `command-execute` what would be the case if this function is invoked by a user pressing a keyboard key.

When invoked directly from within elisp code the function can run as you have specified it, but to avoid the error message you have experienced you need to mark the function as interactive by using the directive `(interactive)` as first statement after the documentation string in the function definition. .

For more details, see [3.3 Make a Function Interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Interactive.html) or visit the *Info* node in *Emacs* with <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(info "(eintr) Interactive")` and the answer to the question ["Why can't I bind my function to a key or call it with M-x?"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/45402/40171).

By the way, knowing how it comes that the error is raised you can "fool" the detection mechanism of an actual interactive call and simulate it from elisp code by running this function using `command-execute`.

Run the code below to see that the function will report that it was called interactively when actually called from elisp script and not by user pressing a key:

```el
(defun interactive-aware-fun ()
  "This function can detect if it was called from script or invoked by 
a keypress using 'called-interactively-p' "
    (interactive); required, else if called by a keypress there will be
    ; ^ an error message:  command-execute : Wrong type argument: commandp, interactive-aware-fun
    (message "interactive-aware-fun called-interactively-p : %s" (called-interactively-p))
)

(interactive-aware-fun)                              ;;      gives nil
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'interactive-aware-fun) ;; [F9] gives  t
(command-execute 'interactive-aware-fun)             ;;      gives  t
```